# Calculate integral with less accuracy using Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, double, integral

I want to calculate a double integral over a rectangular region `(-pi/2, pi/2)x(-pi/2, pi/2)`.

I used the `int` function:

```
double(int(int(...)));
```

The problem is that the running time was too long. But I don't need such an accurate result. How can I calculate this integral with less accuracy so that the I can reduce the running time?

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB's `int` function performs symbolic integration (it is some analogue of Mathematica's `Integrate` function). If you need to compute numerical integral I suggest you to use `dblquad` function for this. You can provide required tolerance of computations with this function.